# collectd write_mongodb plugin lt_dlopen error on fedora 17. collectd does not recognize the installed lib

Tags: fedora, collectd

I have downloaded the libmongoc driver from git repo and make install it. and then I downloaded the collectd tar file, and extract it and try to install it, every thing went ok, but when I try to run collect d I face these error :

```
[path to collectd]# sbin/collectd
ERROR: lt_dlopen ("/opt/collectd/lib/collectd/write_mongodb.so") failed: file not found.
The most common cause for this problem are missing dependencies. 
Use ldd(1) to check the dependencies of the plugin / shared object.
[path to  collectd]# 

[path to collectd]# ldd /opt/collectd/lib/collectd/write_mongodb.so
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff1dbaa000)
libmongoc.so.0.7 => not found
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f8351fd1000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8351c1a000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f83523e4000)
[path to collectd]# 
[path to  collectd]# locate libmongoc.so.0.7
/usr/local/lib/libmongoc.so.0.7
/usr/local/lib/libmongoc.so.0.7.1
[path to collectd]#
```

why collectd does not recognize the installed libmongoc library?

Comment: I got the same errors just like you. Did you solve it ?

Comment: unfortunately no, I wanted to collect my guest vms stats with it, now I use libvirt standard api, to do that.

Answer (score 0):

i successfuly installed collectd with write_mongodb.

```
[root@stackdev ~]# ldd /usr/local/etc/collectd/lib/collectd/write_mongodb.so 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffa3ffe000)
    libmongoc.so.0.6 => not found
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f1134fe8000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1134c2f000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1135614000)
```

and then i copied libmongoc.so.0.6 (i installed it at /usr/local/lib
) into directory of /lib64
and then run collectd ,all works fine.

Hope this can help you.